# could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependencies, .net-assembly

in my solution I have a 3 projects (1 website, 1 data layer, 1 biz layer). 
my biz layer has assembly reference in my both website & data layer and my data layer has a reference in website as well. in my website I have 3 web services that are basically using these data layer & biz layer to work.

now the problem I'm facing is recently I made some changes to one of the classes in this BizEntity which is my biz layer project name and added some fields to one of the current classes and then added a rdlc to my website to provide reporting but in my rdlc design page when I drop a table from tools I get the following error:

```
 "Could not load file or assembly 'BizEntity', Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

*BizEntity is the project name of my biz layer which contains the objects.

I've been searching internet for solution for so long & I couldn't find any working solution for it. any help or suggestion would be appreciated the most.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your data layer skips the business layer and needs web site info directly, or vice versa, you're doing the layering wrong.

Comment: No the data layer is using business layer completely, I'm not quiet sure but maybe it's because I made some changes to my business layer and its reference is not updated in data layer or the website? I'm not quite sure just throwing guesses. but thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: I just made a new website in the same solution, added the business layer dll to the bin folder, created a rdlc file, droppe the table in the page and got the same error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Build of project with RDLC cannot find custom assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624617/build-of-project-with-rdlc-cannot-find-custom-assembly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

copy data layer and biz layer dlls in

> server root:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\DataDesign

restart VS.

Comment: +1 for your answer, that fixed the problem. Thank you so much for your help and others as well for their comments. But what could possibly cause the problem Ashish?

Comment: This didn't work for me. However, copying the dlls in question to the \common7\ide\privateAssemblies folder did work. This is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624617/build-of-project-with-rdlc-cannot-find-custom-assembly

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with ajaxtoolkit, adding the ajax library to the mentioned folder resolved the problem. I added *SanitizerProviders.dll*, *AjaxControlToolkit.dll*, *HtmlSanitizationLibrary.dll*, and then finally restarted VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

Check that  folder properties which store BizEntity is "Read-only" or not.

Comment: yea it was read-only and I unchecked it but still not working. Thanks for fast reply anyway